# text is disappearing when filling the gradient for uilabel, custom uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uilabel

My goal is to add gradients for my uilabel by doing the following (**CustomLabelBackGround** is subclass of UILabel)

```
@implementation CustomLabelBackGround

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
    CGContextRef context        =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGColorRef whiteColor       =   [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef lightGrayColor   =   [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef separatorColor   =   [UIColor colorWithRed:208.0/255.0 green:208.0/255.0 blue:208.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    CGRect paperRect            =   self.bounds;

    // Fill with gradient
    drawLinearGradient(context, paperRect, whiteColor, lightGrayColor);

    // Add white 1 px stroke
    CGRect strokeRect           =   paperRect;
    strokeRect.size.height     -=   1;
    strokeRect                  =   rectFor1PxStroke(strokeRect);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, strokeRect);

    // Add separator
    CGPoint startPoint          =   CGPointMake(paperRect.origin.x, paperRect.origin.y + paperRect.size.height - 1);
    CGPoint endPoint            =   CGPointMake(paperRect.origin.x + paperRect.size.width - 1, paperRect.origin.y + paperRect.size.height - 1);
    draw1PxStroke(context, startPoint, endPoint, separatorColor);

}
```

However, the text of CustomLabelBackGround is disappearing when I am trying to display onto the screen. please look at the picture below as reference:

[image]

What I am missing here. Please help if you have any ideas about this. thanks

Comment: When implementing DrawRect on a label, you will have to draw the text also. Try applying the gradient to a UIView and putting the label over it or draw the text also.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call :

```
[super drawRect:rect];
```

in order to super draw your text before drawing your anything else. The text with then be drawn normaly

Answer (score 1):

Since you are implementing `drawRect` for `UILabel` you are owning that Graphics Context, therefore you are basically "overriding" the text, you can draw that yourself as well, or an easier approach would just be to have a container view with the gradient and a transparent label with the text.

Comment: Or just connect a regular view to the view controller and set insert the gradient there

Answer (score 1):

The best approach

- Create a custom UIView
- make this drawrect implement there
- In this UILabel class add that class as background to the label

Otherwise you have to draw the label contents also since you are overriding its `drawrect` method

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pre-render the gradient in photoshop and then on your label just set:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Create a custom UIView,and use your drawRect code there.
2. Make sure that the UILabel background is set to [UIColor
   clearColor].
3. Add the Custom UILabel Class as a
   subview of the Custom UIView class.

Or just do like Imram said, and create that gradient as an image in Photoshop or some other graphic editor program, and set the label background there.  Personally, I think this may be the simplest and most maintainable solution.